# I'm trying to make a TextView for empty listview but I am unable to get ListView from activity

Tags: android, xml, listview, android-listview, textview

I have a ListView and wish to create a TextView that shows "empty list" when it is empty. 
This is my fragment code.

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
tools:context=".MainActivity$CurrentFragment" >

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/section_label"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

<ListView 
    android:id="@id/android:list"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
/>
<TextView 
    android:id="@id/android:empty"
    android:text="No current orders"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:gravity="center_vertical|center_horizontal" />

<Button
    android:id="@+id/button1"
    android:layout_weight="3"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_width="0dip"
    android:text="@string/submit_button"
    android:onClick="sendMessage" />
<Button
    android:id="@+id/button2"
    android:layout_weight="2"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_width="0dip"
    android:text="@string/clear_button"
    android:onClick="clearOrders" />
```

The ListView id is @id/android:list. How do I use that using R.id in my activity class?

Comment: Hope this helps: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6770267/how-to-use-r-to-select-a-listview-when-using-it-with-listactivity
Are you sure that the id is declared as `@id/android:list` and not as `@android:id/list`?

Comment: If you are not extending your Activity from `ListActivity` your id should be `android:id="@+id/list"` and for TextView `android:id="@+id/empty"`

Answer (score 2):

As Abhishek stated, you should use @+id/empty and @+id/list if your activity is NOT extending `ListActivity`.

Also, after you instantiate your ListView, you will want to call the following if you are not extending `ListActivity`:

```
mMyListView = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.list);
mMyListView.setEmptyView((View) findViewById(R.id.empty));
```

If you ARE extending `ListActivity`, it should work out when you use `setContentView()`.

The corresponding values are:

```
android.R.id.empty
android.R.id.list
```

Comment: I used your solution. There is a problem. The "empty" message is there ALL THE TIME. Even when the list is not empty. (not using list activity). My listView is in a Fragment and I cannot use ListActivity